# Difficulty centering GridView in Framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, layout

I tried to make my gridview items to be tight to each other 
and the whole gridView layout to be centered

My gridview code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="?attr/BottomSheetBackground"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/bottom_dialog_fragment_padding_top"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="32dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/actionGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</FrameLayout>
```

My gridview items code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/actionGridViewItemContainer"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_or_holo"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionGridViewItemImageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionGridViewItemTextView"
        style="@style/Caption.Number_text"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to switch so many option with the GridView such as 
numColumns, columnWidth, stretchMode,
but the situation is that the GridView is align to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution works for me is to put a constant size to my columns items so i will able to calculate my full gridview

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:background="?attr/BottomSheetBackground"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/bottom_dialog_fragment_padding_top"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="32dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/actionGridView"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</FrameLayout>
```